# Using Prism v5 with Reactive UI

Tags: prism, reactiveui

Just wondering if any has successfully managed to make use of PRISM v5 composition features like Regions, and View-Based navigation?  These features, seem complementary to ReactiveUI in their scope but I am wondering if their any any gotchas one needs to keep in mind before trying to use both libraries in the same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33043611/615903) will help you.
All regular features of RxUI will play well within Prism, but one is competing: `RoutedViewHost` and `ViewModelViewHost` (`View` locator by `ViewModel`, or routing navigation)

Basically the gotcha is this:

> Prism tries to resolve a VM type for a given view, whereas RxUI does it the other way around and resolves View for the current VM.

Because of that, mixing them back and forth can be confusing (at best), but you can bind one to a region, and use only RxUI `View` resolver for that region.